# How to get the current padding applied to a modifier in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am passing a modifier instance to a function like this

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposable(modifier : Modifier) {
    
}
```

I want to know the current padding applied to the passed modifier inside the function. How to do this?

```
@Composable
   fun SomeComposable(modifier : Modifier) {
       // val currentTopPadding = modifier.getTopPadding()
  }
```

I know there is nothing like `getTopPadding()` but I want a similar or any other function if there is any which gives me padding

Comment: Why do you want to know the padding?

Comment: @Zun I wanted to add padding if not added previously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from [Adam Powell](https://twitter.com/adamwp) in [Kotlin Slack Channel](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/):

> No, you're not meant to be able to ask this. If you were able to and
> this practice were encouraged it would be prohibitively difficult to
> write UI code that composes with UI code written by others, or to
> combine libraries that are unaware of one another
>
> This is why Android View padding is frighteningly complex - it permits
> querying padding and the set of things considered "padding" is
> unexpectedly large, and has to be for correctness
>
> Padding is an instruction to compose's layout system to subtract
> available space from an element during measurement and to position the
> final measured element within a larger space. It is far from the only
> such instruction available, and app or library code can create their
> own as well.

Here's the [link](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1622985487006600) to his answer.

Comment: It would be very necessary to get Modifier data in many cases where .then is only serial and many params can't be overloaded like offset, size... and so on.